# Would it keep throwing Service Invoked too many times due to a mal-formed HTML email body using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

The code below started failing and throwing:
`Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: email.`

However, if I run a function only sending  a plain text email, it works.
Getting email remaining quota shows 0, though:
`const getEmailQuota = () => { const emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota(); console.log(emailQuotaRemaining) }`

The function that builds and sends the HTML emails:

```
function sendBiWeeklyEmail(taskData, agencyPartnerContactName, approverEmail, msgType, openTasks, accountMngrName, accountMngrEmail, startDate) {

  const fromEmail = 'noreply@somedomain.com';
  const toEmail = 'someEmail@gmail.com'
  const bccEmails = 'someEmail2@hotmail.com';

  const client = taskData[1][1];
  const currentMonth = taskData[1][6];
  startDate = Utilities.formatDate(startDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');

  let subject = '';
  let emailBody = '';

  if (msgType === 'endMonth') {
    subject = 'Your Month-End Update is here for ' + client + '!';
    emailBody += '<p>Hello <strong>' + agencyPartnerContactName + '</strong> - this is your month-end campaign deliverable update for <strong>' + client + '</strong>!</p>';
    emailBody += '<p>Campaign Start Date: ' + startDate + '<br>';
    emailBody += 'Current Month: ' + currentMonth + '</p>';

  } else if (msgType === 'midMonth') {
    subject = 'Your Mid-Month Update is here for ' + client + '!';
    emailBody += '<p>Hello <strong>' + agencyPartnerContactName + '</strong> - this is your mid-month campaign deliverable update for <strong>' + client + '</strong>!</p>';
    emailBody += '<p>Campaign Start Date: ' + startDate + '<br>';
    emailBody += 'Current Month: ' + currentMonth + '</p>';
  }

  // Create the table headers
  const tableHeaders = '<tr><th>Task</th><th>Evidence</th></tr>';

  // Initialize the table body for completed tasks and in-progress tasks
  let completedTasksTableBody = '';
  let inProgressTasksTableBody = '';

  // Iterate over taskData and build the table rows
  for (let i = 1; i < taskData.length; i++) {
    const task = taskData[i][3];
    const status = taskData[i][4] ? '✅ Completed' : '⏳ In progress';
    const evidence = taskData[i][5];

    const evidenceLink = evidence !== '' ? '<a href="' + evidence + '">Link</a>' : '';
    const taskRow = '<tr><td>' + task + '</td><td style="text-align: center;">' + evidenceLink + '</td></tr>';

    if (status === '✅ Completed') {
      completedTasksTableBody += taskRow;
    } else {
      inProgressTasksTableBody += taskRow;
    }
  }

  // Build the completed tasks table
  const completedTasksTable = '<table>' + tableHeaders + completedTasksTableBody + '</table>';

  // Build the in-progress tasks table
  const inProgressTasksTable = '<table>' + tableHeaders + inProgressTasksTableBody + '</table>';

  if (completedTasksTableBody !== '') {
    emailBody += '<h4>✅ Completed - these tasks are done!</h4>';
    emailBody += completedTasksTable;
  }

  if (inProgressTasksTableBody !== '') {
    emailBody += '<p>⏳ <strong>In progress</strong> - these tasks are being worked on. Our goal is to complete everything before this email gets sent, but sometimes we may experience delays. Your Account Manager will reach out if any delays need to be addressed.</p>';
    emailBody += inProgressTasksTable;
  }

  emailBody += '<h4>Your Team</h4>';

  const emailOptions = {
    from: fromEmail,
    to: toEmail,
    bcc: bccEmails,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: emailBody
  };
  console.log(emailOptions)

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailOptions.to, emailOptions.subject, '', {
    from: emailOptions.from,
    bcc: emailOptions.bcc,
    htmlBody: emailOptions.htmlBody
  });
}
```

Comment: If you're using a standard consumer account the max number of email you can send per day is 100. So once you exceed that number you're going to get an error.